# Plotting Sorted Values Seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, plot, seaborn

I'm trying to plot a lineplot by sorting to a specific column, however this gets out of order when sorting and trying to plot using seaborn. I've been ordering by the true column but come with the following plot.

```
normalized_evaluation_table = get_evaluation_table(normalized_prediction_intervals, normalized_interval_size, y_test)
#normalized_evaluation_table
normalized_sorted_table = normalized_evaluation_table.sort_values("true", ignore_index = True).reset_index()
normalized_sorted_table
sorted_data_long = normalized_sorted_table.melt(value_vars=['min', 'true', 'max']).reset_index()
sorted_data_long
ax = sns.lineplot(x="index", y="value", data=sorted_data_long, hue = "variable")
```

## Dataset Ordered

[image]

## Current Plot

[image]

## Output Obtained with Accepted Answer:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `matplotlib` to plot the data in columns. In this way, you will have more flexibility. If you like the seaborn style of the plot, you can import its style.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use("seaborn")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
ax.plot(sorted_data_long['index'], sorted_data_long['min'], 'b-')
ax.plot(sorted_data_long['index'], sorted_data_long['max'], 'g-')
ax.plot(sorted_data_long['index'], sorted_data_long['true'], 'r-')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick :) I updated the question with your answer

Comment: I’m glad it worked! You can play with several other styles like ggplot, etc. See here: https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html